# How to wait for outer observable to emit a value then check for condition before subscribing to another observable once?

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
const subscription: Subscription;
const first$      // Observable A
const second$     // Observable B

// When `first$` emits, I am checking the value and 
// subscribe to `second$` if value is more than 5
subscription.add(
   first$.subscribe(value => {
      if(value > 5) {
          subscription.add(
             second$.subscribe((name) => console.log(name))
          );
       }
   });
);
```

`first$` may continue to emit multiple values through app life cycle (Angular). How do I make sure that `second$` do not get subscribed again after it has already been subscribed?

Comment: You might want to look into rxjs switchMap https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Answer (score 1):

Try switchMap:

```
this.second$ = this.first$.pipe(
  filter(v => v > 5),
  // take(1), // if necessary
  switchMap(v => this.doSomethingAsyncWith()),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter, then subscribe one:

```
first$.pipe(filter(v => v > 5), first()).subscribe(() => second$.subscribe((name) => console.log(name)))
```

Answer (score 0):

SwitchMap:

```
    import { BehaviorSubject, EMPTY, interval } from 'rxjs';
    import { map, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

    const first$ = interval(1000).pipe(
        map(() => Math.random() * 10)
    );

    const $second = new BehaviorSubject('second obs');

    first$.pipe(
        tap(resultFirst => console.log('resultFirst', resultFirst)),
        // conditionally subscribe to $second
        switchMap(resultFirst => resultFirst > 5 ? $second : EMPTY),
        tap(resultSecond => console.log('resultSecond', resultSecond)),
    ).subscribe();
```

`switchMap` will automatically unsubscribe the inner observable in case the outer observable emits a new value.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Comment: As @MoxxiManagarm mentioned filter is also good:
        `first$.pipe(
            tap(resultFirst => console.log('resultFirst', resultFirst)),
            filter(v => v > 5),
            switchMap(() =>  $second),
            tap(resultSecond => console.log('resultSecond', resultSecond)),
        ).subscribe();`

Answer (score 0):

Calling subscribe inside a subscribe callback is usually a bad practice. [Operators](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/) are the best way to handle this kind of situation. You can use [filter](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html) along with [skipUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/skipuntil.html) to skip until the value is greater than 5 and then subscribe to the pipe.

```js
import { filter, skipUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

//...

second$.pipe(
  skipUntil(first$.pipe(filter(value =>  value > 5))),
).subscribe((name) => console.log(name))
```